# Howto configure Hudson findbugs plugin to send notification mails

Tags: hudson, findbugs

how do i configure Hudson Findbugs plugin to send a notification mail if a new failure is detected?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what the description for the plugin states as features:

- Failure threshold to mark a build as unstable
- Configurable project health support

The first one won't help you. The second one might give you a chance to fail the build when new failures are detected.

> This plug-in is developed and
>   maintained by Ullrich Hafner. Please
>   use the Hudson mailing lists or issue
>   tracker to ask questions, create
>   feature request or bug reports, since
>   I don't read the comment section on
>   this page regularly.

Since this a very special question, you might be better of using the mailing list. If enough people ask, he might update the plugin documentation.

Comment: thanks Peter, i will check their issue tracker and mailing list.